# Writing out Fokker-Planck equations for stochastic differential equations with multiple independent white noises

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations, noise

If I have a stochastic differential equation in the following form:
$$
\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{A}{B+\sigma_1\Gamma_1}(\sigma_2\Gamma_2 \sin x+\sigma_3\Gamma_3 \cos x) + C\sigma_4 \Gamma_4,
$$
where $\Gamma_i$ are white noises that satisfy $\langle \Gamma_i(t)\rangle=0$ and $\langle \Gamma_i(t)\Gamma_j(t')\rangle=2\delta_{ij}\delta(t-t')$, is it possible to write out a Fokker-Planck equation of $P(x,t)$ for the given stochastic differential equation?

If it is generally not possible, what about for the case of $\sigma_1=0$?

Comment: You can't divide by a function of white noise. Besides that, there's no problem here, you just turn the crank to get a multivariate FPE.

Comment: Is there any references that explicitly state this rule? Or any justifications of it?

Comment: Can you please show explicitly how to combine multiple white noises such that the whole thing becomes the standard form $dX=f(X,t)dt+g(X,t)dW_t$ and write the whole thing into a FPE? Just let $\sigma_1=0$ and pretend we don't see that white noise term in denominator if that's problematic.

Comment: A heuristic justification in this setting is that sometimes that denominator will be zero, so even numerically it wouldn't make sense. But there are more serious problems with making sense of functions that depend nonlinearly on white noise.

Comment: Anyway, it's $dX=\frac{A \sigma_2}{B} \sin(X) dW_1 + \frac{A \sigma_3}{B} \cos(X) dW_2 + C \sigma_4 dW_3$. So you'll want to look at the multivariate version of the FPE.

Comment: (I may have dropped some $\sqrt{2}'s$.)